# Angular js - replace url segments/pieces without refreshing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, replace, segments

Hi i'm trying replacing

`site.com/u#asd` 
with 
 `site.com/u`

in browser url bar , and i would like to not refresh the page while replacing url

Is this possible?

I tryed:

```
$location.replace("#asd","");
```

but it obviously won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're misusing `replace()` - it accepts no arguments, and [its purpose is said to](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24location) replace the history record:

   > If called, all changes to $location during current $digest will be
   >   replacing current history record, instead of adding new one.
2. You should not use replace in the first place. Instead, call `$location.url()`, it will not refresh the page (unless you pass `true` as a second argument).

   From [the `$location` dev guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/%24location):

   > It does not cause a full page reload when the browser URL is changed.